# Trainable array in Tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to train a mixture model but I am unclear how to specify a trainable array argument in order to allow the weights to be updated. So if I have the following with weights hard coded

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

weights = [0.2, 0.8]
dist = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(probs=weights),
            components=[tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0., name='loc1'), scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale1')),
                        tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0., name='loc2'), scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale2'))])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

@tf.function
def train_step(X):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = -tf.reduce_mean(dist.log_prob(X)) 
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss,dist.trainable_variables)     
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, dist.trainable_variables)) 
        return loss

for i in range(20000):
    loss = train_step(X)
```

where X is a 1D Numpy array with shape (272, 1)

Now let's say I want to learn the weights. If I try in the Categorical distribution constructor

```
probs=[tf.Variable(0.2, name='weight1'),tf.Variable(0.8, name='weight2')]
```

then I get an error "No gradients provided for any variable"

if I try

```
probs=tf.Variable([tf.Variable(0.2, name='weight1'),tf.Variable(0.8, name='weight2')], trainable=True, name='weights')
```

then weight1 and weight2 do not appear in the list of trainablevariables. weights is listed but does not update.

What is the correct way to specify the weights to the probs argument so they will be updated during training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

dist = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(probs=tf.Variable([0.2, 0.8])),
            components=[tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0., name='loc1'), scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale1')),
                        tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0., name='loc2'), scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale2'))])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

@tf.function
def train_step(X):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = -tf.reduce_mean(dist.log_prob(X)) 
        tf.print(dist.trainable_variables)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, dist.trainable_variables)     
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, dist.trainable_variables)) #E 
        return loss

for i in range(10):
    loss = train_step(tf.random.normal((272, 1)))
```

```
([0.2 0.8], 0, 1, 0, 1)
([0.2 0.8], -0.00999249145, 1.00999844, -0.0099981213, 1.00999963)
([0.200921655 0.799828708], -0.00638755737, 1.00682414, -0.00639217719, 1.00682521)
([0.20176363 0.799696386], -0.000149463303, 1.00765562, -0.000160227064, 1.00764322)
([0.200775564 0.800094664], 0.000889031217, 1.00637043, 0.000898908474, 1.00636196)
([0.199177444 0.800768435], -0.00115872873, 1.0025779, -0.00113528164, 1.0025754)
([0.19703567 0.801662683], -0.000830670586, 0.998396218, -0.000778611051, 0.998392522)
([0.193336055 0.80336237], 0.00244163908, 0.993740082, 0.00255049323, 0.993718445)
([0.192727238 0.803925216], 0.00376213156, 0.989788294, 0.00386576797, 0.989756942)
([0.194845349 0.802922785], 0.0022987891, 0.986021399, 0.00232516858, 0.985970497)
```

Comment: This is almost right -- instead of `probs` in Categorical, use `logits`. `probs` need to be constrained to sum to 1. `logits` will not have this constraint. Note that the values pretty quickly change and fail to meet this constraint. `logits` is also usually better for numerical precision, though that may not matter too much in this small model. In the background, Categorical will convert `probs` to `logits` anyway.
You'll also want to constrain `scale` to be positive. TFP has a utility for this. Try `tfp.util.TransformedVariable(1., bijector=tfp.bijectors.Softplus(), name='scaleN')`